# list box validation

Tags: asp.net

i want to validate for listBox whether list box is empty of or not i am doing following

```
 protected void isToListEmpty_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (toListBox.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else args.IsValid = true;
    }

    <td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="second" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListBox id="toListBox" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="200" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:CustomValidator id="isToListEmpty" runat="server" OnServerValidate="isToListEmpty_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Select Student Details" ValidationGroup="verify" ControlToValidate="toListBox"></asp:CustomValidator> 

</ContentTemplate>

<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonAdd" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonRemove" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonAddAll" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonRemoveAll" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```

but it doesn't work for empty list box 
 How to check for this? please let me know

Comment: is update panel a reason for  validator not check for the empty listBox?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? If you add a breakpoint in the `ServerValidate` event, is it hit? is the `Items.Count` really zero when the breakpoint is hit? Does this code also fail on an empty page (i.e., maybe other methods / events interfere?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update: answer rewritten.*

The original asker found the following answer (see comments): you must set `ValidateEmptyText` to true.

Comment: it is all there i am not getting what may be  the problem y the break point is not even being hit

Comment: what else code should i post you in order to know you more please let me know?

Comment: oh it does work i was to set property  ValidateEmptyText="true";

Comment: @NoviceToDotnet: that's a valid answer, it seems. Sorry I couldn't check back earlier. For others that find your question, I'll update my answer with your suggestion, if I may.